# How to display the frequency spectrum of an image?

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm trying to display the frequency spectrum of an image using the CImg library. Let's say as a line plot with the frequency value on the x axis and the log intensity on the y axis.

I'm pretty new to the library, so it might as well be quite easy.

Comment: Do you realize that the spectrum will be a function of 2 variables just like the image itself? Anyhow, what's your *specific* question?

Comment: Yes, the fourier transform will give me a real and imaginary part.
I'm not sure what the respective parts represent.
The question is how to get a line plot with the frequency value on the x axis and the log intensity on the y axis.

Comment: A Fourier Transform of a 2d image is also a 2d image (with real and imaginary values of every pixel), it's not a line plot.

Comment: Yes I know that, but that was not the question. Nevermind I've found a workaround for it.